# Python, nginx and Flask, how to execute a php post script - 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED

Tags: php, python, nginx

I have a client side script that i need to execute.  Its a php script that does a post.  My web framework is python flask and nginx using uWSGI as middleware.  The php file is a script that will export a dhtmxlGrid to excel.  When a try and export...the below error is what I get.  I dont known anything about PhP.

Here is the command I am trying to execute.  I have php installed on the server so I believe.  Just did a apt-get install php5.

```
<input type="image" src="static/pix/excel.png" WIDTH=25 HEIGHT=25 value="Get as Excel" onclick="mygrid.toExcel('static/js/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/grid-excel-php/generate.php');">
```

This is the FireFox error I get when I click the export to excel button.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method POST is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

UPDATE:

I added the the below to nginx.conf file.

```
location /static/js/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/grid-excel-php/generate.php {
            access_log   off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
        }
```

Same error.  405.

If I call http://dashboard.com/static/js/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/grid-excel-php/generate.php in the broser, I get a download generate.php dialouge box where I can see the code.  So...guess php is not executed.

Comment: And what happened if you call PHP script from broser?

Comment: If I paste the url with post parms it just downloads the file called generate.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `location` directive in your nginx config that points at `static/generate.php` and renders it using a PHP interpreter. Then inside your flask application you post to the URL defined in your nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

Flask or Python don't know how to interprete PHP, you also to allow POST methods on any routes, the best idea would be to catch the request in nginx and serve it from a php interpreter.

Comment: How do I server from nginx then if I have a file called static/generate.php?

Comment: You need a php interpreter to evaluate and execute the file.